# Is it possible to deploy debug APKs on the play store?

Tags: android, google-play

I'd like to publish **debug** versions of my app to the Google Play Store for alpha/beta testing

- would have a different package name than the production app
- would never be published to the production channel, alpha/beta channels only

The idea would be that I could distribute `fake`, `dev`, `staging` applications alongside our `prod` application

Comment: This question is **off-topic** for Stack Overflow and may be removed. Please see this [official list](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) of topics that Stack Overflow deems _on-topic_

Comment: This is kinda off topic, I agree, but I don't mind giving general advice, I much more mind stupid questions with zero programming skill involved (e.g. '*help me find a bug in my for loop*'). This is actually a valid question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question is no.

As per the alternatives:

> The only way to test your debug version is to generate an apk and send it to your friends in some way and have them install it on their phones or to physically connect their phones and install the app on them

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

Please read the developer agreement to get the details.

Answer (score 0):

##### Since 2021 https://play.google.com/console/about/internalappsharing/

Yes, for internal use.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844679?hl=en-GB&visit_id=637610900578773144-788919652&rd=1

> - You can upload and share debuggable APKs.